# Test If a Bookmark Exists for Each Table in the Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document that contains several tables. Some tables are bookmarked with a bookmark name that begins with "NTS", the others are not bookmarked. I created a negative-step for loop that deletes all tables whose name begins with "NTS"; however, if a table does not have a bookmark, an errors pops out (not unexpected). So I would like to test if there is an associated bookmark for a table and, if not, move on to the next table. My if-statement that attempts to do this doesn't work (starred bellow). Any suggestions?

```
Dim tableCount As Integer
Dim tableNumber As Integer
Dim bookmarkName As String
'
tableCount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
'
For tableNumber = tableCount To 1 Step -1
    ActiveDocument.Tables(tableNumber).Select
    *If Selection.Bookmarks(1).Exists = False Then
        GoTo Furthermore
    End If*
    bookmarkName = Selection.Bookmarks(1).Name
    If Left(bookmarkName, 3) = "NTS" Then
        ActiveDocument.Tables(tableNumber).delete
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).delete
    End If
Furthermore:
Next
```

Comment: Are you using this in Word or VB.net? Looks like word-vba to me.

Comment: Yes, i'm using Word VBA. And, it looks like that did it. Many thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead (Check the method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192733.aspx)):

```
If Selection.Bookmarks.Count = 0 Then GoTo Furthermore
```

The one that you are trying to use needs an argument, the bookmarks name, like below (Check it out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821366.aspx)):

```
Selection.Bookmarks.Exists("NTS_example")
```